# Core-Shell structure using blender?

Tags: modeling

How can I design a gold nanoparticles and titanium dioxide core-shell structure using blender? I can easily make 2 UV sphere as core and shell, but I have no idea what to do afterwards. Please help me guys, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far? It's not clear what you are asking, could you provide more information about what you want to achieve? Please edit you question and add some reference images of what you want to model, and how it should look, and what you have so far

Comment: Hey buddy, I have edited my question by adding 2 sample pictures.The upper one is my target picture, the other one is what I have achieved. I also have no idea how to get the transparent-like color of the shell. thank you

Comment: what is the point finally ? modeling an opening on the eighth of the sphere, the transparent material ? The granularity on the outside part ? all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating the base meshes - step by step.**

In this short tutorial I will only cover the creation of the base mesh without the materials.

1. Add a single uv sphere, hit <kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd> to scale it.
2. Select the vertices for the chunk you want to cut out by going into top view, hitting <kbd>B</kbd> and box-select the vertices. Double-check by rotating and selecting/deselecting additional vertices.

[image: cut out chunk]

3. Hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select "Faces" to delete the selected faces.
4. Go into object mode, then go to the "Modifiers" Tab in the Properties Window, select "add modifier" and chose "Solidifiy".

[image: Solidify]

5. Change "Thickness" in the Modifier settings to your liking.

[image: modify thickness]

6. Add another uv sphere and scale it until it fills the inner part of your solidified sphere (hit <kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>1.6</kbd> to match the values I used in this example)

[image]